# Function to get content by ID

Tags: get-posts, content, functions

I'm trying to get text only content of posts by ID. I modified this function as follows, but at the moment it returns nothing. I cannot see what's wrong with it.

```
function get_the_excerpt_id($post_id) {
    $find = get_posts($post_id); 
    $excerpt = $find->post_content;

    $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
    $output = substr($excerpt, 0, 100);

  return $output;
}
```

Any ideas what's missing?

Marvellous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `get_posts`, which you would use if you wanted to retrieve multiple posts in a loop, you should use `get_post`, [which only retrieves one post by an ID](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post). There is also a built-in excerpt so you might want to go with retrieving `post_excerpt`.

```
function get_the_excerpt_id($post_id) {
    $find = get_post($post_id); 
    $excerpt = $find->post_excerpt;

    $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
    $output = substr($excerpt, 0, 100);

return $output;
}
```